# Constructing black noise with non-standard analysis  

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, nonstandard-analysis, fluid-dynamics, percolation

With noise in the sense of i.i.d. random sequence,
a noise is black if it is not isomorphic to standard Gaussian white noise.

[Tsirelson](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.PR/0301237/) showed the existence of black noise through the scaling limit of coalescing Brownian motion.
[Watanabe](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449701011010) gave a simpler example, also based on a coalescing stochastic flow, but using a singular diffusion.

[Nelson](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/rept.pdf), chap 18, showed how to construct a Brownian motion using non-standard analysis.

I'm wondering if someone tried to construct a black noise using non-standard method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a good answer to your question, but I believe the first black noises were not the Arratia flow (Brownian web).  They appeared earlier in Tsirelson and Vershik's "Examples of nonlinear continuous tensor products of measure spaces and non-Fock factorizations" (although admittedly they were not noises on $\mathbb{R}$, if I recall correctly).  Furthermore your definition of black is not quite correct.  A noise is *non-classical* if it is not isomorphic to standard Gaussian white noise, and black if it has no classical subnoise.

Comment: A remark to the remrk, I think that percolation is known now by a work of Schramm and Smirnov to represent black noise.